# Bitcoin ASIC for ether mining

Tags: dapps

Can a antminer s9 give me a hashrate of 13.5 TH/s even for a few seconds which trying to mine etherium. Albiet electronically, SHA256 computation of ASIC cannot be used for dagger-hashimoto but can it mine even for a few seconds?

Answer (score 2):

It can not mine Ethereum or any other cryptocurrency, except bitcoin forks, wich uses the same proof of work algorithm, even for few or even less then few seconds :)